# Width of a TableColumn in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

In my application, I use a `JTable` with a few resizable columns. At closing, I want the app to store the size of the columns displayed.

My problem is that even if I manually resize the columns, the `getWidth()` function always returns 75 (the default value), no matter the real size of the column. If I look at the `TableColumn` object with the debugger, it's min size is 15, it's max size is 2147483648, it's preferred size is 75 and it's size is 75. But it's displayed size is clearly not 75!

How can I get the real size of my columns?

The code for getting the widths :

```
        for(i=0;i<TableOpérations.getColumnCount();i++){
              tc=TableOpérations.getColumn(TableOpérations.getColumnName(i));

              width=tc.getWidth();
    }
```

Comment: did you use GUI Builer, otherwise no issue

Comment: Please show an SSCCE so we can reproduce what you _really_ do :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the behavior you're seeing. The following program displays the correct width each time the button is pressed. You must be displaying the widths of the columns of another table or table column model.

```
public class TableColumnTest extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;

    public TableColumnTest() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table = new JTable(5, 4);
        p.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton b = new JButton("Test");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayWidths();
            }
        });
        p.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(p);
        pack();
    }

    private void displayWidths() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            System.out.println("Width of column " + i + " : " + column.getWidth());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableColumnTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well no. In my JInternalFrame, I have a JScrollPane which contains my JTable named "TableOpérations". And that's it!

Comment: I have added the code for getting the width in my question (see above).

Comment: The bug is somewhere else. Provide an SSCCE as asked by Kleopatra. I suspect you have two tables with the same variable name (one local and one instance variable). But that can only be confirmed by seeing the code.